# Анимация диаграммы процесса дизайн-мышления

Tags: css, css3, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Необходимо анимировать для веб странички **Диаграмму процесса дизайн-мышления**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Сценарий анимации:**

- Движение кривых, показывающих процесс прохождения по этапам диаграммы
- Во время выполнения одного этапа крутится лоадер
- По окончанию выполнения одного этапа лоадер постепенно исчезает
- Появляется зелёный чекбокс, сигнализирующий о завершении этапа
- Начинается выполнении второго этапа и так далее до завершения
  последнего этапа

У меня есть лоадер с тремя сегментами

```css
circle {
fill:none;
stroke:#777777;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="320" height="60" viewBox="0 0 350 60" >   
   
 <circle id="crc1" cx="30" cy="30" r="20" stroke-width="3" 
        stroke-dasharray="33.88 8"  stroke-dashoffset="-4" >
  <animate
    attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
   values="33.88;0"
   dur="0.2s"
   begin="0s"
   repeatCount="indefinite"
   restart="whenNotActive" /> 
 
  </circle>  
  
</svg>
```

Взят отсюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/944006/28748

Анимацию линий со стрелкой можно реализовать, как сделано в этом топике:

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/955002/28748

**Вопрос:** Как это всё собрать вместе, рассчитать тайминги анимаций, чтобы выполнить сценарий?

Comment: я бы все сделал на d3.transition().on('end', () => ...)

Comment: @Stranger in the Q  делай, с удовольствием приму. Я сейчас готовлю свой ответ, но себе ставить галочку нет смысла, так что отдам в хорошие руки :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот потрудился над d3 вариантом (пока что не все анимации).

Тут все рассчитывается в рантайме, анимации синхронизированны программно и запускаются, когда стрелочка достаточно приближается к блокам, удаляется от блоков.

Фокусы d3, которыe я тут использовал:

**1. d3.line().curve()**

```
let line = d3.line().curve(d3.curveCardinal);
```

Этот вызов возвращает функцию-интерполятор, которая принимает на вход массив точек, из которых по выбранному алгоритму (здесь `d3.curveCardinal`) возвращает `d` для `path`.

**2. selection.transition().attrTween(...)**

```
arrow.transition(t).attrTween("transform", function(){return ...});
```

Позволяет задать правило для интерполяции строкового `css` параметра, такого, как `color` или `transform`.

**3. d3.interpolateString()**

Собственно, интерполятор между строковыми значениями. Вызов возвращает функцию, которая производит интерполяцию между строковыми значениями.

---

Вот результат, нажмите на чекбокс, чтобы отредактировать кривую:

```js
let w = 115;
let editPath = d3.select('path.edit-path');

let paths = d3.selectAll('path.path');

let zones = d3.select('g.zones').selectAll('g')
            .data(d3.range(6).map(d => ({i: d, x:135 + d*w})))
            .enter().append('g')
            .attr('transform', d => `translate(${d.x}, 0)`);
    
let circles = zones.append('circle').classed('loader', true)
            .attr('r', 20).attr('cx', 60).attr('cy', 170);
    
let marks = zones.append('path').attr('stroke', 'transparent')
            .attr('fill', 'none').attr('stroke-width', 4)
            .attr('d', "M40,165 l15,20 l20,-30");

let rects = zones.append('rect').attr('width', w).attr('height', 480);

let arrow = d3.select(".arrow");
let pathNode = editPath.node();
let totalLength = pathNode.getTotalLength();

d3.select('input#modify').on('change', () => {
    let editMode = d3.select('input#modify').node().checked;
    paths.classed('no-dasharray', editMode); 
    rects.classed('no-dasharray', editMode); 
    d3.selectAll('circle.knob').classed('no-dasharray', editMode); 
});

editor(editPath);

anim();

function anim() {
    paths.attr('d', editPath.attr('d'));

    draw(true);

    function draw(now) {

      var t = d3.transition()
          .duration(16000)
          .delay(now ? 0 : 1000)
          .on("start", function() {
              d3.selectAll("path").style("display", "block");
              marks.attr('stroke','transparent')  
              circles.attr('stroke', 'transparent')
                  .each(d => {d.started = d.done = d.checked = false});
          })
          .on("end", draw);

      arrow.transition(t).attrTween("transform", function() {
          return function(t) {
            let pos = t * totalLength;
            let pt = pointAtLength(pos); 
            circles.each(function(d) {
                let dx = Math.abs(d.x - pt[0] + w/2);
                if (!d.started && dx < w/2) {
                    d.started = true;
                    d3.select(this) .transition(100).attr('stroke', 'black');
                }
                if (!d.done && d.started && dx > w/2) {
                    d.done = true;
                    d3.select(this).transition(300).attr('stroke','transparent')   
                }
            })
            marks.each(function(d) {
                if (!d.checked && d.done) {
                    d.checked = true;
                    d3.select(this).transition(300).attr('stroke','green')   
                }
            })
            return `translate(${pt}) rotate(${tangentAt(pos)})`;
          };
        });

        paths.transition(t).attrTween("stroke-dasharray", function() {
          return d3.interpolateString("0," + totalLength, totalLength + "," + totalLength);
        });

        circles.transition(t).attrTween("stroke-dashoffset", function() {
          return d3.interpolate(0, 1000);
        });
    }

    function pointAtLength(l) {
      let xy = pathNode.getPointAtLength(l);
      return [xy.x, xy.y];
    }

    function tangentAt(l) {
      let a = pointAtLength(Math.max(l - 0.01, 0)), 
          b = pointAtLength(l + 0.01); 
      return Math.atan2(b[1] - a[1], b[0] - a[0]) * 180 / Math.PI;
    }
    
}

function editor(target) {
    let size = 800;

    let points = d3.range(0, 13).map(function(i) {
      return [135 + i*w/2, 250-100*Math.random()];
    });

    let dragged = null,
        selected = points[points.length-1];

    let line = d3.line().curve(d3.curveCardinal);

    let svg = d3.select("svg");

    svg.append("rect")
        .attr("width", size)
        .attr("height", size);

    d3.select(window)
        .on("mousemove", mousemove)
        .on("mouseup", mouseup);

    redraw();

    function redraw() {

      paths.datum(points).attr("d", line);  
      
      totalLength = pathNode.getTotalLength();
        
      var circle = svg.selectAll("circle.knob")
          .data(points, d => d);

      circle.exit().remove();

      let newNodes = circle.enter()
          .append("circle").classed('knob', true)
          .attr("r", 1e-6)
          .on("mousedown", d => { 
              selected = dragged = d; 
              redraw(); 
          })
          .transition()
          .duration(250)
          .attr("r", 6.5);

      circle.merge(newNodes)
          .classed("selected", d => d === selected)
          .attr("cx", d => d[0])
          .attr("cy", d => d[1]);

      if (d3.event) {
        d3.event.preventDefault();
        d3.event.stopPropagation();
      }
    }

    function mousemove() {
      if (!dragged) 
          return;
      let m = d3.mouse(svg.node());
      dragged[0] = m[0];
      dragged[1] = m[1];
      redraw();
    }

    function mouseup() {
      if (!dragged) 
          return;
      mousemove();
      dragged = null;
    }

}
```

```css
rect {
    fill: none;
}

circle.loader {
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 2.2px;
    stroke-dasharray: 32 10;
}

path.path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width:2.2;
}

circle {
  fill: transparent;
  cursor: move;
}

.no-dasharray {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 !important;
    stroke: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<input id="modify" type="checkbox">modify</input>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
     viewBox="0 0 960 500">
    <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ5NF.jpg" 
           height="100%" width="100%"/>
    <g class="zones"></g>
    <path class='path edit-path'/>
    <path class='path mirror-path' transform='translate(0,520) scale(1, -1)'/>
    <path class="arrow" d="M-5,0 L-15,15 L15,0 L-15,-15 Z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: не плохо получилось, но от такого мастера как ты, я честно говоря ожидал бОльшего. Во-первых путь не может быть произвольным, Он должен быть именно таким как в вопросе на картинке. Во-вторых задумка была, - пока идёт выполнение одного этапа лоадер крутится, затем исчезает. В третьих, - **решение не адаптивно** и это самый главный минус. Ну и я конечно ожидал, что ты добавишь дополнительно, какие-то новые яркие анимационные эффекты.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT дык это все не 45 секунд делается, я вчера до 2х часов ночи и так с этим просидел =) вечером сегодня еще подпричешу =), я тут больше хотел показать возможность не рисовать руками, а программировать анимации, потом еще и описание напишу

Comment: Давай Константин жду :) Плюс я уже давно поставил, жду когда можно галочку будет отдать. Хотя не в этом дело, просто как я понял, нам с тобой доставляет удовольствие просто заниматься творчеством  А репа, медальки за этим сами придут  :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT я вот mirror для path сделал, но захардкодил Y относительно которого отражение происходит, и застрял на его подсчете.

Comment: да не торопись, я буду ждать сколько надо будет. Но змею двуглавую, надо меньше сделать, чтобы не залазила на картинки и текст. И не выходи за габариты картинки слева и справа, там могут быть другие блоки.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT я хочу возврат обязятельно чтобы был, иначе не интересно =), а кривую подрихтуем

Comment: про вращение лоадеров не забудь

Comment: @Alexandr_TT это я на закуску оставил =)

Comment: Замечательно. Мне очень понравилось. Особенно фича с изменением пути. Очень классный ответ и решение!

Comment: @Alexandr_TT спасибо за акцепт, я часто именно этим кусочком кода пользуюсь для рисования всяких сплайнов "по месту", а потом готовую svg из отладчика достаю, попозже доделаю копию стрелочки и цвет кривых =)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/WmROQO

Comment: так я с утра посмотрел  не заметил по сердечку? :) или это ссылка для других?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT теперь заметил, а там есть оповещения?

Comment: не знаю, скорее всего нет

Comment: @Alexandr_TT а этот кусок кода частичка моего доморощенного svg редактора, на d3 под браузер

Comment: Вот ещё очень похожий по применению генератор [криволинейных патчей](https://codepen.io/anthonydugois/pen/mewdyZ) даю ссылку, может не видел

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, да, только это несколько другое, по приведенной ссылке редактор кривой с контрольными точками, тут же - сплайн, причем алгоритм можно легко изменить и будет другой тип интерполяции

Comment: @Alexandr_TT я такой прием использую для редактирования уже сгенерированных интерполятором путей, вот так это выглядит https://imgur.com/a/juOBaYM

Comment: напомнило [гладкую поликривую Безье второго порядка](https://svg-art.ru/?p=1118)

Answer (score 11):

- Движение кривых, показывающих процесс прохождения по этапам диаграммы

  Загружаем картинку в векторный редактор и с помощью инструмента - *Рисовать кривые Безье*, повторяем траекторию кривых.
- Сохраняем патчи кривых в другой файл и реализуем анимацию роста
  кривых с помощью  `stroke-dashoffset`. При уменьшении этого
  атрибута от `1192px` до нуля, линия будет расти от нуля до максимума.

```css
.shape svg {
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
}
#outline1, #outline2 {
  fill:none;
 
 stroke-dasharray: 1192;
  animation: dash 17s linear forwards;
  stroke-linejoin: round; 
  stroke-width:4;
 } 

@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1192;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
.container {

width:100%;
height:100%;
background-image: url("https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/3px-tile.png"); 
background: linear-gradient(to right,#B452A0, #895FDD );
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="90%" height="90%" viewBox="0 0 1214 863" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">

 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ5NF.jpg" height="100%" width="100%"/>
    <path id="outline1" stroke="#EC1E4E" d="m62.2 447c0 0 33.3-38.2 48.5-58.5 12.5-16.7 19.9-37.4 34.7-52.1 13.4-13.3 29.7-24.9 47.5-31.1 16.2-5.6 34.2-7.1 51.2-4.6 18.5 2.7 35.8 11.8 52.1 21 23.5 13.2 43.4 30.3 64.9 48.5 17.3 14.6 39.6 25.5 62.2 27.4 21.3 1.8 41.6-9.9 62.2-15.5 20.5-5.6 40.4-13.7 61.3-18.3 18.6-4.1 37.6-8.4 56.7-8.2 19.4 0.1 39.4 2.3 57.6 9.1 20.5 7.7 36.1 25.1 55.8 34.7 21 10.4 42.4 23.1 65.8 24.7 21.8 1.5 44.6-4.5 64-14.6 19.9-10.4 38.4-16.2 58.5-21 18.8-4.5 38.2-7.4 57.6-7.3 20.9 0.1 41.8 3.6 62.2 8.2 19.1 4.3 36.9 13 55.8 18.3 15.4 4.3 46.6 11 46.6 11v0M62.2 447"/>
  <path id="outline2" stroke="#8B0FC5" d="m62.2 447c0 0 33.3 38.2 48.5 58.5 12.5 16.7 19.9 37.4 34.7 52.1 13.4 13.3 29.7 24.9 47.5 31.1 16.2 5.6 34.2 7.1 51.2 4.6 18.5-2.7 35.8-11.8 52.1-21 23.5-13.2 43.4-30.3 64.9-48.5 17.3-14.6 39.6-25.5 62.2-27.4 21.3-1.8 41.6 9.9 62.2 15.5 20.5 5.6 40.4 13.7 61.3 18.3 18.6 4.1 37.6 8.4 56.7 8.2 19.4-0.1 39.4-2.3 57.6-9.1 20.5-7.7 36.1-25.1 55.8-34.7 21-10.4 42.4-23.1 65.8-24.7 21.8-1.5 44.6 4.5 64 14.6 19.9 10.4 38.4 16.2 58.5 21 18.8 4.5 38.2 7.4 57.6 7.3 20.9-0.1 41.8-3.6 62.2-8.2 19.1-4.3 36.9-13 55.8-18.3 15.4-4.3 46.6-11 46.6-11v0" />
   
  </svg> 
  </div>
```

Все дальнейшие пояснения даны в комментариях кода.

Тайминг последовательных и параллельных анимаций осуществляется цепочками условий основанных на привязке к `id` анимаций.

Другими словами, `begin="an_check1.end-0.5s"` - данная анимация начнется, когда закончится анимация с `id="an_check1"` минус пол секунды.

```css
.shape svg {
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
}
#outline1, #outline2 {
  fill:none;
 
 stroke-dasharray: 1192;
  animation: dash 17s linear forwards;
  stroke-linejoin: round; 
  stroke-width:4;
  
} 



@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1192;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
.container {

width:100%;
height:100%;
background: linear-gradient(to right,#B452A0, #895FDD );
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="90%" height="90%" viewBox="0 0 1214 863" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">

<defs>


</defs>

 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ5NF.jpg" height="100%" width="100%"/>
    <path id="outline1" stroke="#EC1E4E" d="m62.2 447c0 0 33.3-38.2 48.5-58.5 12.5-16.7 19.9-37.4 34.7-52.1 13.4-13.3 29.7-24.9 47.5-31.1 16.2-5.6 34.2-7.1 51.2-4.6 18.5 2.7 35.8 11.8 52.1 21 23.5 13.2 43.4 30.3 64.9 48.5 17.3 14.6 39.6 25.5 62.2 27.4 21.3 1.8 41.6-9.9 62.2-15.5 20.5-5.6 40.4-13.7 61.3-18.3 18.6-4.1 37.6-8.4 56.7-8.2 19.4 0.1 39.4 2.3 57.6 9.1 20.5 7.7 36.1 25.1 55.8 34.7 21 10.4 42.4 23.1 65.8 24.7 21.8 1.5 44.6-4.5 64-14.6 19.9-10.4 38.4-16.2 58.5-21 18.8-4.5 38.2-7.4 57.6-7.3 20.9 0.1 41.8 3.6 62.2 8.2 19.1 4.3 36.9 13 55.8 18.3 15.4 4.3 46.6 11 46.6 11v0M62.2 447"/>
  <path id="outline2" stroke="#8B0FC5" d="m62.2 447c0 0 33.3 38.2 48.5 58.5 12.5 16.7 19.9 37.4 34.7 52.1 13.4 13.3 29.7 24.9 47.5 31.1 16.2 5.6 34.2 7.1 51.2 4.6 18.5-2.7 35.8-11.8 52.1-21 23.5-13.2 43.4-30.3 64.9-48.5 17.3-14.6 39.6-25.5 62.2-27.4 21.3-1.8 41.6 9.9 62.2 15.5 20.5 5.6 40.4 13.7 61.3 18.3 18.6 4.1 37.6 8.4 56.7 8.2 19.4-0.1 39.4-2.3 57.6-9.1 20.5-7.7 36.1-25.1 55.8-34.7 21-10.4 42.4-23.1 65.8-24.7 21.8-1.5 44.6 4.5 64 14.6 19.9 10.4 38.4 16.2 58.5 21 18.8 4.5 38.2 7.4 57.6 7.3 20.9-0.1 41.8-3.6 62.2-8.2 19.1-4.3 36.9-13 55.8-18.3 15.4-4.3 46.6-11 46.6-11v0" />
    <!-- Верхний  Бегущий треугольник -->
  <polyline transform="translate(7 -12.5) rotate(90)" points="0,0 12.5,21.6 25,0" fill="#B51092" >
  <animateMotion
    id="an1_triangle"
    dur="17s"
    repeatCount="1"
    rotate="auto-reverse"
    begin="0s"
    fill="freeze"
    restart="whenNotActive">
     <mpath xlink:href="#outline1"/>
 </animateMotion>  
 <!-- Нижний  Бегущий треугольник -->
</polyline>  
    <polyline transform="translate(7 -12.5) rotate(90)" points="0,0 12.5,21.6 25,0" fill="#6326DD" >
  <animateMotion
    id="an2_triangle"
    dur="17s"
    repeatCount="1"
    rotate="auto-reverse"
    begin="0s"
    fill="freeze"
    restart="whenNotActive">
     <mpath xlink:href="#outline2"/>
   </animateMotion>  
    </polyline>   
    <!-- Лоадер 1-ой секции -->
 <g transform="translate(30 265)">
  <circle id="crc1" cx="30" cy="30" r="20" fill="none" stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#EC1E4E" stroke-width="3" 
   stroke-dasharray="33.88 8"  stroke-dashoffset="-4" >
        
    <animate id="an_crc1"
    attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
    values="33.88;0"
    dur="0.2s"
    begin="0s"
     repeatCount="12"
    restart="whenNotActive" /> 
                 <animate id="fill_crc1"  attributeName="stroke-opacity" dur="1s" begin="an_crc1.end-0.5s" values="1;0" fill="freeze" />  
  </circle>   
       <!-- Анимация чекбокса 1-ой секции -->  
      <text x="15" y="43" fill="#00AF00" font-size="54" fill-opacity="0">&#10004;
    <animate id="an_check1"
       attributeName="fill-opacity"
    dur="1s"
    begin="fill_crc1.end-0.25s"
    values="0;1"
    fill="freeze" /> 
   </text>
    </g>   
     <!-- Лоадер 2-ой секции -->
 <g transform="translate(330 265)">
  <circle id="crc2" cx="30" cy="30" r="20" fill="none" stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#CA0C52" stroke-width="3" 
   stroke-dasharray="33.88 8"  stroke-dashoffset="-4" >
        
    <animate id="an_crc2"
    attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
    values="33.88;0"
    dur="0.2s"
    begin="an_check1.end-0.5s"
    repeatCount="12"
    restart="whenNotActive" /> 
                 <animate id="fill_crc2"  attributeName="stroke-opacity" dur="1s" begin="an_crc2.end-0.5s" values="1;0" fill="freeze" />  
  </circle>   
       <!-- Анимация чекбокса 2-ой секции -->  
      <text x="15" y="43" fill="#00AF00" font-size="54" fill-opacity="0">&#10004;
    <animate id="an_check2"
       attributeName="fill-opacity"
    dur="1s"
    begin="fill_crc2.end-0.25s"
    values="0;1"
    fill="freeze" /> 
   </text>
    </g>      
 
         <!-- Лоадер 3-ой секции -->
 <g transform="translate(530 265)">
  <circle id="crc3" cx="30" cy="30" r="20" fill="none" stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#B51092" stroke-width="3" 
   stroke-dasharray="33.88 8"  stroke-dashoffset="-4" >
        
    <animate id="an_crc3"
    attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
    values="33.88;0"
    dur="0.2s"
    begin="an_check2.end-0.5s"
    repeatCount="12"
    restart="whenNotActive" /> 
                 <animate id="fill_crc3"  attributeName="stroke-opacity" dur="1s" begin="an_crc3.end-0.5s" values="1;0" fill="freeze" />  
  </circle>   
       <!-- Анимация чекбокса 3-ой секции -->  
      <text x="15" y="43" fill="#00AF00" font-size="54" fill-opacity="0">&#10004;
    <animate id="an_check3"
       attributeName="fill-opacity"
    dur="1s"
    begin="fill_crc3.end-0.25s"
    values="0;1"
    fill="freeze" /> 
   </text>
    </g>  
    
            <!-- Лоадер 4-ой секции -->
 <g transform="translate(730 265)">
  <circle id="crc4" cx="30" cy="30" r="20" fill="none" stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#8B0FC5" stroke-width="3" 
   stroke-dasharray="33.88 8"  stroke-dashoffset="-4" >
        
    <animate id="an_crc4"
    attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
    values="33.88;0"
    dur="0.2s"
    begin="an_check3.end-0.5s"
    repeatCount="12"
    restart="whenNotActive" /> 
                 <animate id="fill_crc4"  attributeName="stroke-opacity" dur="1s" begin="an_crc4.end-0.5s" values="1;0" fill="freeze" />  
  </circle>   
       <!-- Анимация чекбокса 4-ой секции -->  
      <text x="15" y="43" fill="#00AF00" font-size="54" fill-opacity="0">&#10004;
    <animate id="an_check4"
       attributeName="fill-opacity"
    dur="1s"
    begin="fill_crc4.end-0.25s"
    values="0;1"
    fill="freeze" /> 
   </text>
    </g>    
 
               <!-- Лоадер 5-ой секции -->
 <g transform="translate(930 265)">
  <circle id="crc5" cx="30" cy="30" r="20" fill="none" stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#6326DD" stroke-width="3" 
   stroke-dasharray="33.88 8"  stroke-dashoffset="-4" >
        
    <animate id="an_crc5"
    attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
    values="33.88;0"
    dur="0.2s"
    begin="an_check4.end-0.5s"
    repeatCount="12"
    restart="whenNotActive" /> 
                 <animate id="fill_crc5"  attributeName="stroke-opacity" dur="1s" begin="an_crc5.end-0.5s" values="1;0" fill="freeze" />  
  </circle>   
       <!-- Анимация чекбокса 5-ой секции -->  
      <text x="15" y="43" fill="#00AF00" font-size="54" fill-opacity="0">&#10004;
    <animate id="an_check5"
       attributeName="fill-opacity"
    dur="1s"
    begin="fill_crc5.end-0.25s"
    values="0;1"
    fill="freeze" /> 
   </text>
    </g>    
 
                  <!-- Лоадер 6-ой секции -->
 <g transform="translate(1085 265)">
  <circle id="crc6" cx="30" cy="30" r="20" fill="none" stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#0336E1" stroke-width="3" 
   stroke-dasharray="33.88 8"  stroke-dashoffset="-4" >
        
    <animate id="an_crc6"
    attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
    values="33.88;0"
    dur="0.2s"
    begin="an_check5.end-0.5s"
    repeatCount="12"
    restart="whenNotActive" /> 
                 <animate id="fill_crc6"  attributeName="stroke-opacity" dur="1s" begin="an_crc6.end-0.5s" values="1;0" fill="freeze" />  
  </circle>   
       <!-- Анимация чекбокса 6-ой секции -->  
      <text x="15" y="43" fill="#00AF00" font-size="54" fill-opacity="0">&#10004;
    <animate id="an_check6"
       attributeName="fill-opacity"
    dur="1s"
    begin="fill_crc6.end-0.25s"
    values="0;1"
    fill="freeze" /> 
   </text>
    </g>  
    
 
  
  </svg> 
  </div>
```

**Приложение полностью адаптивно. Работает во всех современных браузерах.**

Анимация не работает в IE и Edge, так как *Microsoft* не хочет поддерживать анимацию SVG.
Да и многое другое, в том числе современные технологии CSS3, плохо или совсем не поддерживаются браузерами *Microsoft*.

Comment: Ого, интересная вещь. Спасибо за вопрос и подробный ответ